# Speed up numerical optimization (for plotting and solving)?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, performance-tuning, numerical-value

Briefly speaking, I want to plot a function `PIfun[]`, which its value is based on numerical optimization using `NMaximize`.

It just takes so long, especially if the optimization is using `SearchPoints->200`. I wonder if it's possible to speed up such problems.

And, if I expect the shape of the curve to cross 0, so I want to solve for the roots, say using `FindRoot[]` or `NSolve[]`, it also take a long time.

Is there a better solution to this?

Thanks!

(* Now the full story *)
To begin with, here is the code:

```
skinks = {56, 19, 28, 18, 24, 14, 9};
kskinks = 7;
B1997 = {14,10,6,3,3,6,2,3,2,1,1,1,0,3,2,0,3,1,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,0,1};
kB1997 = 50;
B1998 = {14,9,7,4,2,4,4,0,4,2,0,1,0,3,0,3,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,2,0,1,0,1,1};
kB1998 = 50;

(* Gauss Hermite *)
myghxw[n_Integer] := Module[
    {xis, wis, getw, x},

    (* get xi *)
    xis = NSolve[HermiteH[n, x] == 0, WorkingPrecision->30];
    xis = Cases[xis, _?NumericQ, Infinity];
    (* get wi *)
    getw[xi_] := 2^(n - 1)*n!*Sqrt[Pi]/(n^2*HermiteH[n - 1, xi]^2);
    wis = getw[#] & /@ xis;
    {xis, wis}
];

{xsgh,wsgh} = myghxw[50];

mylikBinLNB[data_, kdata_, f0_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, mu_?NumericQ, sigma_?NumericQ] := Module[
    {K, pj, fj, N0, loglik, above, below},

    K = kdata;

    (* Using Gauss Hermite *)
    (* Evaluted at each xs *)

    pj = Table[
            1/Sqrt[Pi]*
            (1/(1 + Exp[-xsgh[[i]]*sigma*Sqrt[2] - mu]))^j*
            (1 - 1/(1 + Exp[-xsgh[[i]]*sigma*Sqrt[2] - mu]))^(K - j)
            , {i, 1, Length[xsgh]}
            , {j, 0, K}
        ];

    (* Put weights on *)

    pj = wsgh.pj;

    (* add on binomial *)

    pj = 
        w*Table[p^j*(1-p)^(K-j),{j,0,K}]
        +
        (1-w)*pj;

    (* adjust for constant *)

    pj = pj*Table[Binomial[K, j],{j,0,K}];

    fj = Prepend[PadRight[data,K], f0];

    N0 = Sum[fj[[j]], {j, 1, Length[fj]}] ;
    above = LogGamma[N0 + 1] ;
    below = Sum[LogGamma[fj[[j]] + 1], {j, 1, Length[fj]}] ;
    loglik = fj.Log[pj] ;

    loglik = above - below + loglik;

    If[Im[loglik]!=0,loglik=-9999];

    loglik

];


{time, {maxloglik, mle}} = NMaximize[
    {
        mylikBinLNB[
            skinks,kskinks,
            f0,w,p,mu,sigma
        ],
        f0>=0,
        0<w<1,
        0<p<1,
        sigma>0
    },
    {f0,w,p,mu,sigma},
    MaxIterations -> 1000,
    Method -> {"RandomSearch","SearchPoints" -> 1}
] // AbsoluteTiming ;



PIfun[f0_?NumericQ] := 

Module[

    {proflik},

    proflik = NMaximize[
        {
            mylikBinLNB[
                skinks,
                kskinks,
                f0, w, p, mu, sigma
            ],
            0<w<1,
            0<p<1,
            sigma>0
        },
        {w,p,mu,sigma},
        MaxIterations -> 1000,
        Method -> {"RandomSearch","SearchPoints" -> 200}
    ];

    proflik = proflik[[1]];

    proflik = proflik + Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[1], 0.95]/2 - maxloglik;

    proflik
];
```

The line

```
{time, {maxloglik, mle}} = NMaximize[ ....
```

runs just under 38 seconds on my laptop with a single point. But I want to try like 200 points. It's just too slow. The `skinks` datasets is also small. With a bigger dataset like `B1997`, a single run will take about 1min to run. It's impossible to run 200 `SearchPoints`.

Further to that, I want to plot the function `PIfun[]`. It takes really long, if I just `Plot[]` it. So I have decided to take some points, like this

```
mle = Cases[mle, _?NumericQ, Infinity]
xf0 = Table[i, {i, Max[mle[[1]] - 100, 0], mle[[1]] + 100, 100/10}]
{time, yval} = PIfun[#] & /@ xf0  // AbsoluteTiming;
time
```

Then I can plot like this
    ListLinePlot[Thread[{xf0, yval}]

But I keep getting error messages, like this:

[image]

I tried to change the Precision, but it does not seem to be getting any better.

After the plot, I also want to determine the zeros of the function, like this

```
FindRoot[ PIfun[x] == 0, {x, 0} ]
```

which also take a looooong time.

So, what's the way to get around with functions like this?

Comment: A short description of what the code is supposed to achieve would be nice

Comment: @belisarius I did try to make it shorter, but in order to make it workable with my actual problem. I have taken the "complicated" model, shown above. I hope you can understand that. The main difficulty are the two `NMaximize` routines. I hope to speed them up, for plotting and solving for zeros.

Comment: Please try to trigger your issue and edit your question with the actual error, not just the whole code.